# When a row is checked, the whole row turns black

Tags: checkbox, bootstrap-table, checked

When using checkbox in bootstrap-table every row that is selected turns black, how can I manage the colors or a I missing a library or something

[bootstrap-table checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxfbw.png)

I tried a CSS attribute change but nothing happened

Comment: Without you posting the CSS code, we cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not share the CSS file, I am using an example of "selected" class for your td element. Do override the background color of your row like this:

```
.selected tr{
   background-color:white !important;
 }
```